# Aggregate data by hour based on Timestamp

Tags: mysql

This must be a common thing to want to do, but I'm stuck.

I have some data that could be simplified like this:

```
id    user    unixtime
-----------------------
1     dave    1335312057
2     dave    1335312058
3     steve   1335312128
```

etc.

So far, I have only needed to aggregate by day, so I've been using:

```
SELECT
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime))) AS time,
 count(c.user) AS count
FROM core c
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime))
```

I've tried using CONCAT with DATE and HOUR, but can't quite get it working as expected – any ideas?

Comment: Please expand on "can't quite get it working as expected".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
 DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) as date,
 HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) AS hour,
 count(c.user) AS count
FROM core c
GROUP BY 1,2
```

if you want the hour as a unix timestamp, wrap this query to get it:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(the_date, INTERVAL the_hour HOUR)), the_count
from (select
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) as the_date,
    HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) as the_hour,
    count(c.user) AS the_count
    FROM core c
    GROUP BY 1,2 
) x
```

Note: Used `the_` prefix on column names to avoid problems with reserved words

Comment: Almost, but I really want the return to be a unix timestamp - I can of course parse that data back in PHP, but it would be nicer if it came out here as unix timestamp – would you recommend using CONCAT to build up a mysql time stamp, then using UNIX_TIMESTAMP to turn it into a unix one, or is there a better way?

Comment: i.e., I'm testing using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime))," ",HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)),":00:00"))` in the SELECT clause, which works, but seems like it might be a little complicated for something that perhaps is easier.

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot. By the way, do you have any good books/websites that deal with the more advanced but useful part of SQL/MySQL? I often get pretty far, but don't know enough to think of your second bit, and don't know things such as your `1,2` syntax.

Comment: Actually, this site has lots of good sql kung fu buried in the answers. You could try surfing questions tagged with [tag:sql].

Comment: Good idea, I have learnt a huge amount from SO – I have `mysql` as favourite tag, but not `sql`, I'll add it and see what I can learn! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
SELECT
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)), INTERVAL HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)) HOUR)) AS TIME,
     COUNT(c.user) AS COUNT
    FROM core c
    GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime)), HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixtime));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This kindof does, but the return values for TIME are all rounded to the nearest day, rather than hour.